# Preserve css min and max width before overflow-x takes effect

Tags: css, css-float, styling

With a few columns, I would like the first column to resizbale to a min and max width before any overflow of the parent container takes place.  Effectively to have a min-max width before the overflow-x of the columns container is overflowed.

I've generated a comprehensive minimalist example of what I'm referring to here: http://cssdesk.com/KKtBt

Ideally I would want column-one to be minimum 425px and be able to grow until 600px if there's room.

How might I accomplish that here?

Thanks!

[EDIT]
A simpler example of what I'm trying to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zkjsc

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

It has a parent  that expands out to a max of 1200px wide (customize to suit), and a fixed right hand column that is always static.   Using a calc() call in the {width} is really the easiest way to do the classic 'fixed right column' problem --just make sure you do prefixes correctly.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/opus13/pen/eIqxG)

Comment: Hm, interesting use of calc(), I'd prefer to not use "[an experimental technology](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc)" though

Answer (score 0):

This is really not possible in CSS alone.

See the [discussion](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/21819/help-cant-use-min-and-max-width-in-multi-column-layout#Item_15) here to understand more specifics.

Essentially, to have consistent reliable behavior, Javascript must be used to control the width of the column needing to be resized.